# Nginx doesn't serve static

Tags: django, static, nginx

I'm running Django on Ubuntu Server 9.04.

Django works well, but nginx doesn't return static files - always 404.

Here's the config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    #site_media - folder in uri for static files
    location /static  {
        root /home/user/www/oil/oil_database/static_files;
        autoindex on;
    }

    #location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mov) {
    #   root /home/user/www/oil/oil_database/static_files;
    #   access_log off;
    #   expires 30d;
    #}

    location / {
        root html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        # host and port to fastcgi server
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/home/user/www/oil/oil_database/oil.sock;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log;
}
```

Nginx version is 0.6.35.

All directories exist and made 777 (debugging paranoia). The commented-out block doesn't help when I uncomment it.

Comment: srry, i don't understand what do you mean

Answer (score 62, accepted):

How is your directory setup? Do you have a folder `static` in `/home/user/www/oil/oil_database/static_files`? In that case, the directive should look like this (note the trailing slash in `/static/`):

```
location /static/  {
    autoindex    on;
    root /home/user/www/oil/oil_database/static_files;
}
```

If you want to map the path `/home/user/www/oil/oil_database/static_files` to the URL `/static/`, you have to either

- rename the folder `static_files` to `static` and use this directive:

  ```
  location /static/  {
      autoindex    on;
      root /home/user/www/oil/oil_database/;
  }
  ```
- use an alias:

  ```
  location /static/  {
      autoindex    on;
      alias /home/user/www/oil/oil_database/static_files/;
  }
  ```

See the documentation on the [`root`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#root) and [`alias`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#alias) directives.

Comment: no, there is no "static" dir. Thank you, i'll try out the alias.

Comment: I'm having this very same issue however the solutions here do not seem to be working for me. I've posted my own question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131830/django-using-nginx-to-serve-static-content/24131959#24131959

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar config for my Django sites, but I think you want to use `alias` instead of `root` for your media.  For example:

```
location /static {
    alias /home/user/www/oil/oil_database/static_files;
}
```