# Nginx , SImple configuration for serving all the files in a Directory and all the directories within

Tags: django, nginx, pinax, static-files

I am looking for a simple configuration to serve all files and directories inside a particular folder.

To be more precise I am trying to serve everything inside the pinax `/static_media/` folder and `/media/` folder as it is with the same url, and preferably auto index everything .

by the way I have run `python manage.py build_media --all` so all static content is under `<project_name>/site_media/static`

The current configuration I am using :

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  QuadraPaper;

    access_log  /home/gdev/Projects/QuardaPaper/access_log.log;

    location ^*/site_media/*$
    {
        autoindex on;
        access_log off;
        root /home/gdev/Projects/QuardaPaper/site_media;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        root   /home/gdev/Projects/QuardaPaper/media/;
    }
```

All the different configuration instructions from various sites has really confused me , for example

[How to serve all existing static files directly with NGINX, but proxy the rest to a backend server.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869001/492561)

http://coffeecode.net/archives/200-Using-nginx-to-serve-static-content-with-Evergreen.html

https://serverfault.com/q/46315/91723

http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

http://pinaxproject.com/docs/0.7/media/#ref-media-devel

Environment information:

- Xubuntu 10.04 running on VirtualBox
- nginx 1.1.4
- pinax 0.72
- django 1.0.4
- fastcgi for running django via nginx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer , It was Quite simple as i guessed .
One has to set the root directory once and use the sub-directories as the location

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  QuadraPaper;

    access_log  /home/gdev/Projects/QuardaPaper/access_log.log;
    root /home/gdev/Projects/QuardaPaper;

    location /site_media/ {
        autoindex on;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

I got a clue from

[Nginx doesn't serve static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474374/nginx-doesnt-serve-static)