# Static Files not being displayed in Production

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

**EDITED TO SHOW UPDATED CONFIGURATION**

No static files are being shown in Production. Files are showing correctly in Development

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATIC_ROOT = '/opt/soundshelter/static/'

print "Base Dir: " + BASE_DIR #this returns /opt/soundshelter/soundshelter/soundshelter
print "Static Root: " + STATIC_ROOT #this returns /opt/soundshelter/static/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),

) #/opt/soundshelter/soundshelter/soundshelter/static
```

Files are being called in the applications with 
`<link href="{% static "css/portfolio-item.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">`

Using Nginx and Gunicorn.

**Nginx config:**

```
server {
    server_name 46.101.56.50;

    access_log yes;

    location /static {
        autoindex       on;
        alias /opt/soundshelter/static/;
}

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }

#       error_log /opt/soundshelter/soundshelter/soundshelter/nginx-error.log;

}
```

Running `python manage.py collectstatic` reports files were successfully copied but are still not being displayed.

Deployment handled by Fabric

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm

env.hosts = []

print "Here we go..."

def commit():
    local("git add . && git commit")

def push():
    local("git push origin master")

def prepare_deploy():

    commit()
    push()

def deploy():
    code_dir = '/opt/soundshelter/soundshelter/'
    with cd(code_dir):
        run("git pull")
        run("python manage.py collectstatic -v0 --noinput")
        run("service nginx restart")
        run("ps aux |grep gunicorn |xargs kill -HUP")
        run("gunicorn -b PROD_IP soundshelter.wsgi:application")

commit()
push()
deploy()
```

Comment: How are you serving those files to begin with? Using the `staticfiles` app? It its default configuration, it only works in `DEBUG` mode. You might want to [start with the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/).

Comment: @Franco no, you didn't. You haven't said anything at all about how you're serving these files.

Comment: misread the comment, updated question now

Comment: By the way, why your `settings.py` file is located in static folder in dev? It should not be there. Moreover, based on that, your BASE_DIR is `/static/`...

Comment: @chem1st typo :) updated now

Comment: Add this in your **nginx conf**, `error_log /opt/soundshelter/soundshelter/soundshelter/nginx-error.log;`. And then check the error log.

Comment: @JRodDynamite No errors actually being reported upon running...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems to me that your edited `STATICFILES_DIRS` points to the wrong folder, since you have `/static/` folder, not `/staticfiles/`. Should be as it was originally:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Second, `STATIC_ROOT` should point to the static folder which will be served by webserver in pro (but preferably not in project folder). In your case:

```
STATIC_ROOT="/opt/soundshelter/soundshelter/soundshelter/static/"
```

I usually place static folder near the project one and use dynamic `STATIC_ROOT` instead of hardcoding:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
#this will alow to collect your static files in /opt/soundshelter/soundshelter/staticfiles/static
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'staticfiles/static')
```

Now you should do `collectstatic` and it will collect all static files in the `STATIC_ROOT` directory.

Comment: thanks. I followed this exactly but unfortunately it didn't work. Same issue.

Comment: One more time, your `STATIC_ROOT` points at `/opt/soundshelter/static/` but printing `STATIC_ROOT` results in `/opt/soundshelter/soundshelter/staticfiles/static`. How this can be? What I recommend you is to set your `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT` as I showed in my answer and do `collectstatic` then. Next try to open some of your static files (css file or img) by directly requesting it in the url. Print what you'll get here.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, updated now to reflect the correct output. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Running Collectstatic copies files as expected and viewing files such as  http://www.domain.com/js/ajax.js returns a 404

Comment: "As expected" means that all files are collected in `/opt/soundshelter/static/`? You get 404 cause you are trying to open a file in  a wrong place, should be `domain.com/static/js/ajax.js`

Answer (score 0):

In your Nginx Config did you try to set:

```
location /static {
```

instead of

```
location /static/ {
```

also make sure the user running nginx has read permissions to the static folder.

Comment: just tried that and it didn't make any difference, unfortunately. Restarted Nginx after making the change. Also updated read permissions using 'sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/soundshelter/static'

Comment: I also tried all the variations here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1474427/545966 but nothing worked.

Answer (score -1):

**BAD SOLUTION - DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

Adding this to `urls.py` did the trick

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: No! As it is said in docs: "This is not suitable for production use!". It can be used only during development.

Comment: @chem1st Noted and removed from urls.py   ......and now it doesn't work again :-) Question updated with current configurations.